# How to ignore newlines in javascript regexp?

Tags: javascript

I have simple example:

```
data = data.replace(/\/\*(.*?)\*\//g,"")
```

How to ignore newlines in this regexp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'.' doesn't match newlines.  In order to match newlines, you need to have the character set [\s\S], in other words you would have:

```
data = data.replace(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g,"")
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dt4XK/) for a quick demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Add `m` (multiline) to your regexp options

```
data = data.replace(/\/\*(.*?)\*\//gm,"")
```